# Returning sender/from address on outlook in compose mode via VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have just one exchange account on outlook and access to two shared/group mailbox or mail address which are created by admin. I am just a member of that shared mail group and I can send and receive mails via them. So sometimes I make a mistake by choosing wrong sender address. I need to check sender/from address and recipients before sending emails. However, I can't return sender/from addresses as a string via VBA. I choose them by 'from' drop down menu.

Here is my code:

```
Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i
Dim prompt As String
Dim Send_Address As String
Dim checker As Integer

Send_Address = Item.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress

checker = 0

Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set recip = Recipients.Item(i)

    If InStr(LCase(recip.Address), "abc.com") Then
    checker = 1
    End If

    If InStr(LCase(recip.Address), "xyz.com") Then
    checker = 2
    End If

Next i

If (Send_Address = "abc.om") And (checker = 1) Then
    MsgBox ("Please check CC list. It includes different clients.")
    Cancel = True
ElseIf (Send_Address = "xyz.com") And (checker = 2) Then
    MsgBox ("Please check CC list. It includes different clients.")
    Cancel = True
Else
    MsgBox ("OK" & checker & Send_Address)
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with using SendUsingAccount property?

Answer (score 0):

The From value is in `.SentOnBehalfOfName`. It is not updated on a GUI change.

Update the value with code. The GUI will remain unchanged.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub updateFromValue()

Dim Item As mailItem

Dim mailbox1 As String
Dim mailbox2 As String
Dim mailbox3 As String

Dim resp As String

' first create a draft for testing
Set Item = ActiveInspector.currentItem
Item.Display

Debug.Print ".SentOnBehalfOfName: " & Item.SentOnBehalfOfName

mailbox1 = "abc.com"
mailbox2 = "xyz.com"
mailbox3 = "default.com"

resp = InputBox("1: " & mailbox1 & vbCr & "2: " & mailbox2 & vbCr & "3: " & mailbox3)

If Len(resp) > 0 Then

    Select Case resp

    Case 1
        Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = mailbox1
        Debug.Print "Item.SentOnBehalfOfName: " & Item.SentOnBehalfOfName
        
    Case 2
        Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = mailbox2
        Debug.Print "Item.SentOnBehalfOfName: " & Item.SentOnBehalfOfName
        
    Case 3
        Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = mailbox3
        Debug.Print "Item.SentOnBehalfOfName: " & Item.SentOnBehalfOfName
        
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "?"
    
    End Select
    
End If

End Sub
```

Now you can verify the value of `.SentOnBehalfOfName` in Application_ItemSend.